# Move_uploaded_file() function working on Linux server but not on Windows server

Tags: php

I am having an issue. I created a form from where people can apply for jobs. I have 3 fields where I allow users to upload resume, references and other materials. This form works perfectly on my server which is linux based. When I uploaded it to a windows server, I get the following errors:

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(./application/D:\Temp\php\php945C.tmp_tumblr.png) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: Invalid argument in D:\Hosting\9664396\html\application.php on line 23
Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move 'D:\Temp\php\php945C.tmp' to './application/D:\Temp\php\php945C.tmp_tumblr.png' in D:\Hosting\9664396\html\application.php on line 23
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
if(isset($_FILES["photoToUpload"]['name'])){
        $original_img_name = $_FILES["photoToUpload"]['name'];
    } else {
        $original_img_name = "";
    }

    $the_photo_url="None Uploaded";
    if($original_img_name != ""){
        $target = './application/';

        $img_name = str_replace("&", "and", $original_img_name);
        $img_name = preg_replace('/[^.a-zA-Z\d\s]+/s', '', $img_name);
        $img_name = str_replace('  ', ' ', $img_name);
        $img_name = str_replace(' ', '_', $img_name);
        $img_name = str_replace("/", "", $_FILES["photoToUpload"]['tmp_name']) . "_" . $img_name;

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photoToUpload"]['tmp_name'], $target . $img_name);
        $the_photo_url = $target . $img_name;
    }
```

This code is working perfect on my host which is linux based.

Comment: It looks like your path is not being generated correctly: `./application/D:\Temp` etc. Please [post your code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) here, or else we can't help you.

Comment: Please provide us with your code,  seem you've used  invalid  destination path, ./application/D: .....

Comment: I added the code. Thx for taking a look at this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The next line is wrong, you should remove it as you are adding the tmp_name to the $img_name.

```
$img_name = str_replace("/", "", $_FILES["photoToUpload"]['tmp_name']) . "_" . $img_name;
```

Comment: I'm sorry. Which line is wrong? What should I remove?

Comment: The line before `move_uploaded_file` function

Comment: I think that worked but now I am getting the following errors:Warning: move_uploaded_file(./application/tumblr.png) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in D:\Hosting\9664396\html\application.php on line 23

Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move 'D:\Temp\php\php89B7.tmp' to './application/tumblr.png' in D:\Hosting\9664396\html\application.php on line 23

Comment: This is a problem with the destination folder, you are in windows system but the path you are specifiyng is a unix path (./application/tumblr.png) I am not familiar with php in windows environments but i thing this could be the error, I don't know if you can use dot (.) as current directory and if you can use / as directory separator instead of \. Try to us an absolute path to see if it works like $target="D:\Hosting\9664396\html\application\" or using a better approach $target = dirname(_ _FILE__).'\application\'; Notice that I have putted a space before _FILE__ you must remove it

Comment: Thanks David. Really appreciate your help! I just had to change the file permissions and it's working now. I have the same issue. I am not familiar with php in windows environment either.